# How to display a dynamic double

Tags: java, android

I have found a script to display "soundwaves" with a meter. I have been editing this script to make it perfect just for me. But now it only shows bars to display if the device notice some sounds, but i want to display the actual number.

i have been editing this code in the class: soundmeter

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;

public class SoundMeter {
    static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private double mEMA = 0.0;

    public void start() {
            if (mRecorder == null) {
                    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null"); 
                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mRecorder.start();
                mEMA = 0.0;     
            }
    }
    public void stop() {
            if (mRecorder != null) {
                    mRecorder.stop();       
                    mRecorder.release();
                    mRecorder = null;
            }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
            if (mRecorder != null)
                    return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
            else
                    return 0;
    }         

    public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
            double amp = getAmplitude();
            mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
            return mEMA;       
    }

}
```

In the `public void start()` the mediarecorder starts and the mEMA starts with 0.0.

eventually, at the end the code returns `mEMA`, a `double`. I want to display this number on the screen, in a textview, i have already made a textview with the id: amplitude, in my `main.xml`
Also i have tried some snippits to convert a double into a string, but when i test the application, it shuts down. Maybe i place the code on the wrong place or something. So my question is: How can i display the double mEMA?

Comment: post the whole code. every number can be converted in its string equivalent using String.valueOf

Comment: Post `logcat` details here.

Comment: mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");  you does not own the permission to write inside /dev

Comment: Can i get that permission in the manifest?

Comment: And i am not actually recording a file,

Comment: no only root can write inside dev. still I can not quite understand what`s your issue

Comment: Allright, i'll explain. This script reads the amplitude (the sound), and i want that sound to be displayed as a number, like a decibel meter.

Comment: Start a thread that periodically sets your textview with the return value of getAmplitudeEMA().